# PHP parsing error help (working with MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

It says the error is in the while loop.

```
    <?php

    $my_connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

    if(!$my_connection){
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    echo 'Connected successfully' . '<br><br>';

    $my_database = mysql_select_db('jihoon');

    if(!$my_database){
        die('Could not find database: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $query='SELECT * FROM comments";

    $result=mysql_query($query);

    $my_rows;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $my_rows = $my_rows . "id : {$row['id']}";
    }

    mysql_close($my_connection);

    ?>
```

Comment: did you see this error:  $query='SELECT * FROM comments"; you need to use two of the same brackets quotes.  $query="SELECT * FROM comments";

Comment: hopefully you are using a password for you db and just filled in custom values for post...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the syntax-coloring of your question, here on StackOverflow, you'll notice that it starts getting broken at this line :

```
$query='SELECT * FROM comments";
```

**You must use the same kind of quote at the beginning and end of your string.**

So, you should use either :

```
$query='SELECT * FROM comments';
```

or :

```
$query="SELECT * FROM comments";
```

But not a bit of both ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query='SELECT * FROM comments";
```

should be

```
$query="SELECT * FROM comments";
```

Answer (score 1):

`$query = 'SELECT * FROM comments";`

Change to:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM comments";`

Different quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a double quote in end $query='SELECT * FROM comments";